# Guideline and/or Minimal Working Examples for Developing New Theory Solvers for Z3

Tags: z3

From the many questions previously asked on StackExchange, I understand that that the theory
plugin is now deprecated in Z3 4.x and one is now expected to write their own theory solver and compile Z3 from scratch.

However, I cannot find any guidelines and/or simple working examples on how to implement such new theory solvers. Is there somewhere that I have missed already available? If not, has anyone written a new theory solver that they can share the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no official examples or documentation for new theories yet. First, you should decide whether you need an actual theory that is integrated with all the other theories in the smt kernel, or whether your goal can be achieved within a tactic (which might require much less coding effort).

I'm currently working on a theory plugin for floating-point numbers, which is a particularly simple theory because it only translates floating-point constraints to bit-vectors (and then Booleans). This part is not yet in the master branch, but you can see it in the  `fpa-api` branch at [src/smt/theory_fpa.cpp/.h](https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/smt/theory_fpa.cpp) (make sure that the right branch is selected on the webpage, otherwise you'll just see stubs that are not implemented yet.)

Comment: I looked at theory_fpa, tactics and all documentations on Z3 C/C++/Python API. If I'm right, the reason I do not see any callbacks added to Z3 engine in your code is that your theory does not do extra reasoning. That is, bit vectors can completely represent fpa and theory_fpa really serves as an interface to enable users to work with numbers instead of bit sequences. However, I'm interested in theories with extra reasoning power like Nikolaj's paper on Engineering new theories. Are there any simple theory implementation such as those theories? If not, I would have more specific questions.

Comment: That's correct, theory_fpa is a particularly simple example. I'm not aware of other similarly simple examples for this purpose. On the high level though, the only thing missing here is assign_eh and final_check. You'll have to decide how much of the work you want to do in assign_eh, and how much of it will be done when final_check is called. Of course, you can also look at all the other theory implementations. src/smt/smt_theory.h contains the base class for theories with lots of comments.